# how to use react* to solve while the page is not completed loaded when the page is blank?

Tags: reactjs

while I build a page using react, I found it would be blank for few while when the build `javascript` is not completed loaded. I guess the build package is quite large and this makes it load quite slow. during this time the page stays in blank,

how to solve or avoid this ?

:)

Answer (score 1):

There are two options you could follow --> 1. Make the app isomorphic (render pure html on first page load) or 2. Display a message or loading giff in the div where you are loading your app into (it will get replaced by the app when it loads).

Answer (score 0):

To complete @deowk answer you can also try to minify your JS. It depends on which build tool you use (Webpack, Grunt, Gulp, ...) but you should be able to find a module/plugin to uglify your JS.